# Как в Excel задать диапазон с помощью переменных? Как в C# задать строку с помощью переменных?

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

У меня есть накладная, которая сохраняется в эксель последовательно, мне нужно объединить некоторые ячейки,

```
Excel.Range _excelCells1 = (Excel.Range)sheet.get_Range("A1", "A6").Cells;
                _excelCells1.Merge(Type.Missing);
```

Как правильно изменить этот код, чтобы адрес диапазона можно было задавать с помощью переменных?

Answer (score 1):

"A1", "A6" определяет диапазон ячеек, которые объединяются: от A1 до A6. При новом сохранении нужно просто указать требуемый (новый) диапазон.

Если ячейки сдвигаются по вертикали, то адресовать их можно так: "A" + i.ToString(). Или можно задавать диапазон как Range(sheet.Cells[i, 1], sheet.Cells[i + 5, 1]).

Comment: я не могу просто так указать новый диапазон, всё должно быть автоматически, у меня есть цикл, который определяет сколько накладных сохранено уже в таблице 
                int q = 1;
                int j = 0;

                while (sheet.Cells[1 + j, 2].Text != String.Empty)
                {
                    j = j + 15;
                    q++;
                }
и по нему сдвигаются ячейки:
                    sheet.Cells[1 + j, 2] = textBox6.Text;

                    sheet.Cells[1 + j, 1] = "Требование - накладная №"; 
                    sheet.Cells[1 + j, 4] = "Коды";

Comment: Сделал для примера выравнивание текста в ячейках, и выдаёт ошибку, что нужно изменить? 
Excel.Range _excelCells11 = sheet.get_Range(sheet.Cells[1, 1], sheet.Cells[14, 11]);
                    _excelCells11.HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    _excelCells11.VerticalAlignment = -4108;

Comment: В каком месте, какая ошибка?

Comment: Проверил, вот этот код "oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[26, 5] ,oSheet.Cells[27, 7] ).HorizontalAlignment = -4108;" (название переменной oSheet и числа принципиального значения не имеют) работает. Проще для начала отладить код в самом Excel на VBA, а потом переносить его в программу. На VBA строка кода будет выглядеть очень похоже: "oSheet.Range(oSheet.Cells(26, 5), oSheet.Cells(27, 7)).HorizontalAlignment = -4108"